# Does Dividing by Zero in Python Crash Windows 98, et al?

Tags: python, windows

I was told by a professor that dividing by zero or taking a negative square root in Python crashes if you do it in Windows 98.

This seems ridiculous since Python is an interpreted language, but I don't have a way to verify this, and Windows is notorious... Can anyone confirm or deny the claim? If so, does it have to do with the fact that Python is written in C? (And would C really crash the whole OS for division by zero!?)

Comment: Did your professor say that Python crashes when running on Windows, or that Windows crashes? Those are two different things.

Comment: Which version of Python is this claim made for?

Comment: @JoelMueller: "Crash Windows 98, et al?"  "crash the whole OS".  Seems clear that they were told the OS could be stopped by an ordinary math error.

Comment: @S.Lott: "taking a negative square root in Python crashes if you do it in Windows 98" doesn't say anything about crashing the OS. It might be contradicting the bits you quoted, which is why I asked. It seems like it might be the part that most directly quotes the professor.

Comment: Python, by definition, raises a ZeroDivisionError when the second argument of a division is zero. If it crashes, then by definition, it is not Python :). And if the OS crashes, by definition, it is not an *operating* system :).

Comment: @S.Lott That windows crashes, and no version of Python was specified. Let's assume the most recent version of Python that was considered stable on Windows 98

Comment: @Bean: "Let's assume" nothing.  Please get the facts.  I can easily write a version of Python that crashes any computer.  I have to doctor the source, of course, but I can compile it and built it and it will run quite nicely.  My private bad build is not something we can simply "assume" isn't the root cause of the claim.

Comment: I wonder if your professor had a [486SX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80387#80487) or 486DX back then. Having or missing a floating point coprocessor might make all the difference in the world...

Comment: I'll repeat here what I said in a comment below, his original point is that you should never let a program divide by zero (understandable) but his justification is that the whole OS could crash, which I claim is ridiculous in general, and that a programmer should not be responsible for a buggy build that breaks the Pyhon spec. I believe he meant it happens in general on 98, and not from one particular experience he had with a bad compiler.

Comment: @Bean: "I'll repeat here what I said in a comment below..." Bad policy.  Rather than repeat a comment, please **update** the question and remove the duplicative comments.  Please  **update** the question to be complete and consistent.

Comment: @Bean: "I believe he meant it happens in general on 98,".  Then take Python **out** of the question and focus on the actual question -- whatever that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should result in a `ZeroDivisionError` exception.  I can't imagine why this would be different in Windows 98.

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

What a remarkable waste of time.

### Under Win98 with Python 2.3.5

```
Python 2.3.5 (#62, Feb  8 2005, 16:23:02) [MSC v.1200 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

    ****************************************************************
    Personal firewall software may warn about the connection IDLE
    makes to its subprocess using this computer's internal loopback
    interface.  This connection is not visible on any external
    interface and no data is sent to or received from the Internet.
    ****************************************************************

IDLE 1.0.5      
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getwindowsversion()
(4, 10, 67766446, 1, ' A ')
>>> sys.version_info
(2, 3, 5, 'final', 0)
>>> 1/0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in -toplevel-
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, but... do you have (a) a Windows 98 machine and (b) this Python build?  It's almost impossible to disprove the farcical claim because it's always possible that the prof had some Python source that was built with a bad POSIX library package or some bad C compiler.  We don't really know much about the **claim**, do we? Python's fine.  C libraries are fine.  But...

Comment: (b) Which Python build?  Would you expect Python 2.7 on Win 98 to crash or return a ZeroDivisonError? I'm reasonably confident that a recent build of Python is going to work as expected.  Perhaps if we picked an esoterically old build of Python, we might see that, but that claim of "Python crashes on Win98" would still be false because it does not crash for all builds of Python.  Given the statement in the original question, your points are academic at best.

Comment: The point is that the professor's claim (as reported) doesn't include the Python build.  Your example clearly works.  But what did this mysterious professor use?  "claim of "Python crashes on Win98" would still be true because it crashed for one build of Python.

Comment: His original point is that you should never let a program divide by zero (understandable) but his justification is that the whole OS crashes, which I claim is ridiculous. I believe he meant it happens in general on 98, and not from one particular experience he had with a bad compiler.

Comment: @S.Lott  Sure, if you assume his claim "Python crashes on Win98" was meant as "There exists a Python and Win98 combination that crashes." If, instead, his statement was a statement of absolute fact, we merely need to find a single combination of Python and Win98 that do not crash.  Clearly, the author of the question doesn't know what we're trying to answer either. This is all wild speculation and I still maintain that a general answer with info about the expected behavior based on the info we have is the best we're going to be able to provide.  If someone with Win98 says it works, what then?

Comment: If someone with Win98 says it works, what then?  Precisely.  We only know that some build works and someone claims that another (unspecified) build doesn't work.  We're not "speculating" at all.  We simply don't know.  You have an example that passes.  Someone claims that they have an example that fails.  I give weight to your evidence, since it's reproducible.  But can we discount their evidence?  I think we can only ask for more information.

Comment: @Bean  Done.  Ugh.  Now, what on earth does that do for you?

Comment: Closure :) Quite a waste of time, but I appreciate it. I was hoping someone would randomly have already used Python on Win98 in the past, and could just say no way, but your response is impressive.

Answer (score 6):

```
Python 2.7.2 (Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Joke)] on win98
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(-1) / 0
A fatal exception 0E has occurred at 0028:C0011E36 in VXD VMM(01) +
00010E36.  The current application will be terminated

* Press any key to terminate the current application.
* Press CTRL+ALT+DEL again to restart your computer.  You will
  lose any unsaved information in all applications
```

[image]

---

**disclaimer* : Of course, I made that all up.  I'm inclined to agree with **tito** on this one - a trolling professor is the most likely explanation!

░░░░░▄▄▄▄▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▄▄░░░░░░░
░░░░░█░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▀▀▄░░░░
░░░░█░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒░░█░░░
░░░█░░░░░░▄██▀▄▄░░░░░▄▄▄░░░░█░░
░▄▀▒▄▄▄▒░█▀▀▀▀▄▄█░░░██▄▄█░░░░█░
█░▒█▒▄░▀▄▄▄▀░░░░░░░░█░░░▒▒▒▒▒░█
█░▒█░█▀▄▄░░░░░█▀░░░░▀▄░░▄▀▀▀▄▒█
░█░▀▄░█▄░█▀▄▄░▀░▀▀░▄▄▀░░░░█░░█░
░░█░░░▀▄▀█▄▄░█▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▀▀█▀██░█░░
░░░█░░░░██░░▀█▄▄▄█▄▄█▄████░█░░░
░░░░█░░░░▀▀▄░█░░░█░█▀██████░█░░
░░░░░▀▄░░░░░▀▀▄▄▄█▄█▄█▄█▄▀░░█░░
░░░░░░░▀▄▄░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░▒░░░█░
░░░░░░░░░░▀▀▄▄░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░█░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▀▄▄▄▄▄░░░░░░░░█░░

Comment: Windows 98 is no longer supported by Python 2.6 or later. Many of the required libraries are no present. I'm surprised is successfully installed. See http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html

Answer (score 2):

If I don't be wrong, I remember that for some processors family (AMD?) a division by zero cause a loop onto processor and that cause a system crash (onto win 95 and win 98).

Maybe your professor was referring to that?